# How to get a solid line for yesterday close

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot the yesterday close with a solid line, at the moment it's a dotted line probably because of the trackprice=true

The plot.style_line isn't do anything.
Does anyone have any idea how i can solve this?

This is how I plot it now:

plot(yesterdayClose, title = "Yesterday Close", style=plot.style_line, trackprice=true, color=color.new(color.yellow, 5), linewidth=4, offset=k)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have one line only for the yesterday's price and not for the historical prices, you can use `line()`.

```
line1 = line.new(bar_index, yesterdayClose, bar_index + 1, yesterdayClose, extend=extend.both)
line.delete(line1[1])
```

Comment: Great that works for me, thank you very much it hevae cost me a lot off time, but that's how we learn  ;-)